# Why is this loop (C) producing a segmentation error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is a C program that should accept the terminal's input and return the longest line of the input alongside the length of that line. I know it's not as efficient as it could be made, but I'm trying to write with the few functions I know right now. In running it, it returns a segmentation error. An online debugger points out line 30 (which is flagged in the code below) but doesn't specify the problem. I'm not sure of it either, and I've been looking. What is the source of this error?

By the way, I know that there might be other errors. I want to find those myself. I only need help with that segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 200

int start = 0;
int i, j, k, x, finish;
int longlength;
char text[MAX];
char longest[MAX];

int main()
{
fgets (text, MAX, stdin);

for (i = start; text[i] != EOF; i++)
{
    if (text[i] == '\n')
    {
        finish = i - 1;
        break;
    }
}
for (j = start; j <= finish; j++)
{
    longest[j - start] = text[j];
}
longlength = finish - start;

for (k = finish + 1; (text[k] = '\n') && (text[k] != EOF); k++)
{
start = k;  //*****This is line 30*****
for (i = start; (text[(i + 1)] != '\n') && (text[(i + 1)] != EOF); i++)
{
}
finish = i;
if ((finish - start) > longlength)
{
    longlength = (finish - start);
    for (x = start; x <= finish; x++)
    {
        longest[(x - start)] = text[x];
    }
}
}
printf ("This is the longest line : %s.\n Its length is %d.", longest, longlength);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you check for `EOF` (end of file) and not for `\0`?

Comment: The [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function writes a ***null-terminated** byte string* to the destination array. Also note that there are cases where `fgets` will not write the newline to the destination array, which means you could continue the program with `finish` equal to zero. You should also make sure the `fgets` call doesn't *fail*, which it indicates by returning a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: And regarding the code and the problem it's supposed to solve, there are much more simpler ways to handle it, if you're allowed to use the standard C functions like [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) and [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: What is on line 30?

Comment: for (k = finish + 1; (text[k] = '\n') && (text[k] != EOF); k++), In this loop text[k] is always assigned `\n` and checked against EOF. So the loop should run forever.

Comment: `(text[k] = '\n')` is an assignment not a comparison. Did you mean `(text[k] == '\n')`? If you swap the terms around then this very very common error generates a compiler warning, i.e. `('\n' = text[k])` is invalid and you will get the error at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: An addendum to my last comment, I meant [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) and not `strcmp`.

Comment: If the string you enter is greater than MAX characters then `finish` will never be set and will either be zero or an unknown random value depending on your compiler and target platform

Comment: @Spoonless Since `finish` is defined as a global variable, it will be zero initialized.

Comment: @ArunKuttiyaraVarghese Thank you. I'm seeing that infinite loop run now.

Comment: @Spoonless Thanks to you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text[i]` will never (or almost never) be `EOF` (which is usually defined to be -1), so your first loop won't terminate (unless the string contains a `\n`). Strings in C are null-terminated, and you should be checking for `'\0'`, the null character.

You should try to run the code in a debugger, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are typically terminated by `\0` that's why you have to set that as loop termination.

**In your case:**

```
for (i = start; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    //statements
}
```

Why do not use `EOF`:
You use it for Files, for instance `.csv` or normal `.txt` Files. Normal `char`arrays don't work with that.